# Creating a timestamp from 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I dont know is this will count as duplicate since maybe is more specific, i've been coding a file reader. This data ends formated like this.

```
#StartDate StartTime  EndDate   EndTime  ScanDirection  Sheath_Press  Sheath_Temp  Sheath_Avg  Sheath_Sdev  Sheath_RH  ColSamp_Avg  ColSamp_Sdev  ColSamp_RH  ColSamp_Temp  CPC_A_FlwAvg  CPC_A_Sdev  Sat_Temp  Cond_Temp  SEMS_Errors  MCPC_Errors  Impactr_Press  Min_HV  Max_HV  Bin_Cnts1  Bin_Cnts2  Bin_Cnts3  Bin_Cnts4  Bin_Cnts5  Bin_Cnts6  Bin_Cnts7  Bin_Cnts8  Bin_Cnts9  Bin_Cnts10  Bin_Cnts11  Bin_Cnts12  Bin_Cnts13  Bin_Cnts14  Bin_Cnts15  Bin_Cnts16  Bin_Cnts17  Bin_Cnts18  Bin_Cnts19  Bin_Cnts20  Bin_Cnts21  Bin_Cnts22  Bin_Cnts23  Bin_Cnts24  Bin_Cnts25  Bin_Cnts26  Bin_Cnts27  Bin_Cnts28  Bin_Cnts29  Bin_Cnts30  Bin_Cnts31  Bin_Cnts32  Bin_Cnts33  Bin_Cnts34  Bin_Cnts35  Bin_Cnts36  Bin_Cnts37  Bin_Cnts38  Bin_Cnts39  Bin_Cnts40  Bin_Cnts41  Bin_Cnts42  Bin_Cnts43  Bin_Cnts44  Bin_Cnts45  Bin_Cnts46  Bin_Cnts47  Bin_Cnts48  Bin_Cnts49  Bin_Cnts50  Bin_Cnts51  Bin_Cnts52  Bin_Cnts53  Bin_Cnts54  Bin_Cnts55  Bin_Cnts56  Bin_Cnts57  Bin_Cnts58  Bin_Cnts59  Bin_Cnts60
1086     190404  08:36:48   190404  08:37:49              1          1018        295.5        5.01        0.011         55        0.311         0.003           0         273.1         0.337       0.000     318.2      293.2            0            0            0.1     2.8    2314          1          5          5          3          6          6          9         18         23          14          21          18          26          33          23          27          25          42          42          36          44          33          41          30          49          39          35          37          39          43          51          26          43          36          23          32          29          15          16          27          13          14          14          17          16           7           7          12           4           5           4           5           0           0           1           0           0           0           0           0
1087     190404  08:38:06   190404  08:39:07              0          1019        295.5        5.00        0.013         55        0.311         0.002           0         273.1         0.337       0.000     318.3      293.2            0            0            0.2     2.8    2315          2          2          2          5          5          5         10          6         17          14          15          28          29          31          26          40          28          37          19          33          22          54          38          41          40          39          37          39          43          42          34          40          32          36          31          29          26          23          19          22          16          16          19          15          11           6           6           8           7           1           4           1           2           7           0           1           0           1           1           2
1088     190404  08:39:25   190404  08:40:25              1          1018        295.5        5.00        0.012         55        0.310         0.002           0         273.1         0.337       0.000     318.3      293.2            0            0            0.2     2.8    2314          1          3          3          7          7         18          8          8         19          15          29          30          32          32          35          29          35          38          29          39          41          36          48          44          50          39          32          35          37          42          34          40          26          37          30          28          35          29          19          15          24          16          12           6           9           7           7           6          10           5           5           1           5           0           2           2           1           0           1           0
1089     190404  08:40:42   190404  08:41:43              0          1018        295.5        5.01        0.008         55        0.311         0.003           0         273.1         0.336       0.003     318.3      293.2            0            0            0.2     2.8    2315          0          2          5          5          5         11         10         15         16          21          17          22          30          44          32          42          34          38          30          38          26          33          50          46          40          36          36          46          48          37          37          43          39          36          32          33          23          28          29          15          19          13          14          14          17           9           7          11           5           7           4           3           7           2           1           1           1           0           0           0
1090     190404  08:42:01   190404  08:43:01              1          1018        295.5        4.99        0.008         55        0.310         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.3      293.3            0            0            0.2     2.8    2315          0          4          4          6          8         12         11         20         15          21          19          24          24          33          41          35          28          36          30          49          36          37          48          47          25          47          44          28          37          37          36          41          34          33          29          21          21          20          19          23          16          19          12          12           6           8          10           5           7           7           5           2           3           3           3           2           1           2           0           0
1091     190404  08:43:19   190404  08:44:20              0          1018        295.5        5.00        0.008         55        0.310         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.2      293.2            0            0            0.1     2.8    2315          3          1          1          6          8          7          8          6         11          13          16          22          27          27          34          39          29          44          36          39          41          39          36          30          41          47          47          40          28          40          37          41          34          33          33          35          23          29          18          26          21          23          12          22          16           9           5          12           3           3           6           3           2           0           3           1           1           1           0           3
1092     190404  08:44:37   190404  08:45:38              1          1018        295.5        5.01        0.011         55        0.310         0.002           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.2      293.1            0            0            0.2     2.8    2314          1          2          6          3         12          6         10         15         12          21          25          19          30          33          33          34          35          33          32          31          37          33          38          34          31          27          36          42          42          35          38          41          38          31          32          34          25          30          22          21          23          21           9          19           9          12           5          14           8           3           5           2           2           0           1           3           0           0           0           0
1093     190404  08:45:55   190404  08:46:56              0          1018        295.5        5.01        0.012         55        0.310         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.2      293.1            0            0            0.2     2.8    2314          0          3          2          3          7          6          7         12          9          19          18          18          28          29          30          35          34          29          28          36          35          36          41          39          50          46          43          45          38          30          46          32          40          38          25          25          28          30          20          24          19          17          19          14          12          18          22           8           7           2           5           3           5           4           2           0           1           0           1           0
1094     190404  08:47:13   190404  08:48:14              1          1018        295.5        5.00        0.011         55        0.310         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.001     318.2      293.1            0            0            0.2     2.8    2314          2          1          2          2          8         12          7          7         22          22          22          19          20          37          32          47          42          33          33          38          49          30          36          41          43          52          43          29          53          39          31          41          41          25          22          31          30          20          19          28          18          16          22          10          14           8          10           4           7           7           3           3           4           3           1           0           2           3           0           1
1095     190404  08:48:31   190404  08:49:32              0          1018        295.5        5.00        0.009         55        0.310         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.001     318.2      293.1            0            0            0.1     2.8    2314          0          1          3          9          6          8          6          8         10          13          21          18          31          41          26          34          30          42          32          36          36          45          41          46          55          34          43          49          41          44          50          32          37          32          40          22          22          21          27          22          20          12          14          14          11          10           7           7           3           4           7           3           5           3           1           0           2           1           1           0
1096     190404  08:49:49   190404  08:50:50              1          1019        295.5        5.00        0.013         55        0.310         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.2      293.1            0            0            0.1     2.8    2315          2          3          3         11         10          6          6         13         15          15          33          20          23          34          22          28          29          31          38          41          29          39          37          32          45          40          36          47          44          31          39          32          38          42          28          34          24          16          14          21          15          15          12          10          10          11           7           6           7           5           0           2           0           0           1           0           0           1           0           1
1097     190404  08:51:07   190404  08:52:08              0          1019        295.5        4.99        0.008         55        0.310         0.001           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.2      293.1            0            0            0.1     2.8    2314          3          3          5          2          8         10          8          5         11          14          16          25          23          35          35          38          38          32          40          50          38          43          42          46          37          45          40          42          48          37          43          41          24          31          24          34          24          30          15          28          20           6          20          14          13          15           9           9           6           8           3           3           3           0           2           1           0           1           0           3
1098     190404  08:52:25   190404  08:53:26              1          1019        295.5        5.00        0.010         55        0.310         0.003           0         273.1         0.333       0.001     318.2      293.1            0            0            0.2     2.8    2314          5          2          1         11          8          6         13         13         17          19          19          30          23          36          41          33          39          46          31          39          35          35          34          41          45          54          43          36          36          34          36          22          23          33          32          21          21          21          19          18          17          15          13          10           9          18           8           8           8           3           8           4           0           0           1           2           2           0           0           0
1099     190404  08:53:43   190404  08:54:44              0          1019        295.5        5.01        0.009         55        0.310         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.2      293.1            0            0            0.2     2.8    2314          5          5          5          7          7          3          8          8          8          18          24          32          26          34          29          26          44          33          34          42          32          34          37          40          46          50          49          53          57          57          41          35          35          35          29          31          30          28          25          21          23          14          17           9          14          13          10           8           5           4           1           2           2           2           2           2           2           0           0           5
1100     190404  08:55:01   190404  08:56:02              1          1019        295.5        5.01        0.008         55        0.310         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.1      293.1            0            0            0.1     2.8    2315          2          4          5          3          4         11          5         17         17          14          22          25          31          34          39          35          39          51          40          25          41          38          35          39          48          48          46          54          39          50          35          38          36          28          35          35          22          35          27          19          12          24          10          13          15           6          10           3           8           3           3           6           4           4           5           0           2           1           0           2
1101     190404  08:56:20   190404  08:57:21              0          1018        295.5        5.00        0.012         55        0.310         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.001     318.1      293.0            0            0            0.1     2.8    2314          4          0          3          5          7          3         17          5         10          14          15          15          30          34          33          28          37          33          45          31          44          31          34          46          45          47          52          33          41          39          41          36          45          33          38          51          33          24          26          17          21          26          22           9          21           8           8          10           7           6           5           3           5           6           2           0           0           0           2           4
1102     190404  08:57:38   190404  08:58:39              1          1019        295.5        5.01        0.010         55        0.310         0.002           0         273.1         0.333       0.002     318.1      293.0            0            0            0.2     2.8    2315          3          8          4          5          7         13         16         10         12          25          18          19          30          40          29          36          38          36          40          54          44          44          45          47          44          44          45          39          41          51          41          44          34          34          35          28          13          30          19          18          13          20          15          13          16           9           9           8           7           7           6           2           3           3           0           0           0           0           1           0
1103     190404  08:58:56   190404  08:59:57              0          1019        295.5        5.00        0.012         55        0.310         0.001           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.1      293.0            0            0            0.2     2.8    2315          2          4          3          5          8          4          9         11         12          10          17          28          26          19          30          34          40          41          39          40          45          35          38          56          40          41          44          43          33          42          46          33          40          35          37          24          24          17          21          16          22          16          22           9          10           9          11          12           2           5           7           2           5           2           2           1           1           1           0           2
1104     190404  09:00:14   190404  09:01:15              1          1019        295.5        5.00        0.012         55        0.310         0.000           0         273.1         0.334       0.000     318.1      293.0            0            0            0.1     2.8    2315          5          7          7          7         10          9         16         12         23          23          24          25          29          22          36          34          42          39          55          32          37          37          49          46          39          45          47          42          41          46          40          30          38          31          29          26          36          19          22          19          15          22           8          13           8          13           6          12           5           1           6           7           6           1           1           1           0           0           0           1
1105     190404  09:01:32   190404  09:02:33              0          1019        295.5        5.01        0.009         55        0.310         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.1      293.0            0            0            0.2     2.8    2315          2          2          3          5          6          7          6         11         19          23          28          20          20          23          25          28          43          43          50          35          30          44          42          33          45          56          50          43          46          32          40          30          30          38          33          26          24          25          30          22          15          19          16          12          10           8           9           6           6           6           8           4           3           1           1           1           0           0           0           2
```

and i need want to convert the 4 first columns into 2 columns timestamp or datetime for indexing purposing, Start Datetime and End Datetime.

I've tried creating timestamps but its get little bit buggy. So' the '#StartDate' is long, so i applied `pd.Dataframe.apply()` and passes *str*, since trying to use `pd.to_datetime` dint give result for long. The i did the same but with *pd.Timestamp* and it worked out. But its reading it wrong. The actual format is YYMMDD, and is being type casted into ```2004-04-19. From this point on im a little bit lost.

```
data = pd.read_csv("./data.csv", skiprows=72)
data.columns  = data.columns.str.strip()
data['#StartDate'] = data['#StartDate'].apply(str)
data['#StartDate'] = data['#StartDate'].apply(pd.Timestamp)
#data['#StartDate'] = data['#StartDate'].apply(t)
#data['#StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data['#StartDate'], format='%Y%m%d')


print data.tail(20).to_string()
```

This is the the code i up to now.

UPDATE 1: 
This is what the dataframe looks now.

```
Start Datetime        End Datetime  ScanDirection  Sheath_Press  Sheath_Temp  Sheath_Avg  Sheath_Sdev  Sheath_RH  ColSamp_Avg  ColSamp_Sdev  ColSamp_RH  ColSamp_Temp  CPC_A_FlwAvg  CPC_A_Sdev  Sat_Temp  Cond_Temp  SEMS_Errors  MCPC_Errors  Impactr_Press  Min_HV  Max_HV  Bin_Cnts1  Bin_Cnts2  Bin_Cnts3  Bin_Cnts4  Bin_Cnts5  Bin_Cnts6  Bin_Cnts7  Bin_Cnts8  Bin_Cnts9  Bin_Cnts10  Bin_Cnts11  Bin_Cnts12  Bin_Cnts13  Bin_Cnts14  Bin_Cnts15  Bin_Cnts16  Bin_Cnts17  Bin_Cnts18  Bin_Cnts19  Bin_Cnts20  Bin_Cnts21  Bin_Cnts22  Bin_Cnts23  Bin_Cnts24  Bin_Cnts25  Bin_Cnts26  Bin_Cnts27  Bin_Cnts28  Bin_Cnts29  Bin_Cnts30  Bin_Cnts31  Bin_Cnts32  Bin_Cnts33  Bin_Cnts34  Bin_Cnts35  Bin_Cnts36  Bin_Cnts37  Bin_Cnts38  Bin_Cnts39  Bin_Cnts40  Bin_Cnts41  Bin_Cnts42  Bin_Cnts43  Bin_Cnts44  Bin_Cnts45  Bin_Cnts46  Bin_Cnts47  Bin_Cnts48  Bin_Cnts49  Bin_Cnts50  Bin_Cnts51  Bin_Cnts52  Bin_Cnts53  Bin_Cnts54  Bin_Cnts55  Bin_Cnts56  Bin_Cnts57  Bin_Cnts58  Bin_Cnts59  Bin_Cnts60
1101 2004-04-19 08:56:20 2004-04-19 08:57:21              0          1018        295.5        5.00        0.012         55         0.31         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.001     318.1      293.0            0            0            0.1     2.8    2314          4          0          3          5          7          3         17          5         10          14          15          15          30          34          33          28          37          33          45          31          44          31          34          46          45          47          52          33          41          39          41          36          45          33          38          51          33          24          26          17          21          26          22           9          21           8           8          10           7           6           5           3           5           6           2           0           0           0           2           4
1102 2004-04-19 08:57:38 2004-04-19 08:58:39              1          1019        295.5        5.01        0.010         55         0.31         0.002           0         273.1         0.333       0.002     318.1      293.0            0            0            0.2     2.8    2315          3          8          4          5          7         13         16         10         12          25          18          19          30          40          29          36          38          36          40          54          44          44          45          47          44          44          45          39          41          51          41          44          34          34          35          28          13          30          19          18          13          20          15          13          16           9           9           8           7           7           6           2           3           3           0           0           0           0           1           0
1103 2004-04-19 08:58:56 2004-04-19 08:59:57              0          1019        295.5        5.00        0.012         55         0.31         0.001           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.1      293.0            0            0            0.2     2.8    2315          2          4          3          5          8          4          9         11         12          10          17          28          26          19          30          34          40          41          39          40          45          35          38          56          40          41          44          43          33          42          46          33          40          35          37          24          24          17          21          16          22          16          22           9          10           9          11          12           2           5           7           2           5           2           2           1           1           1           0           2
1104 2004-04-19 09:00:14 2004-04-19 09:01:15              1          1019        295.5        5.00        0.012         55         0.31         0.000           0         273.1         0.334       0.000     318.1      293.0            0            0            0.1     2.8    2315          5          7          7          7         10          9         16         12         23          23          24          25          29          22          36          34          42          39          55          32          37          37          49          46          39          45          47          42          41          46          40          30          38          31          29          26          36          19          22          19          15          22           8          13           8          13           6          12           5           1           6           7           6           1           1           1           0           0           0           1
1105 2004-04-19 09:01:32 2004-04-19 09:02:33              0          1019        295.5        5.01        0.009         55         0.31         0.000           0         273.1         0.333       0.000     318.1      293.0            0            0            0.2     2.8    2315          2          2          3          5          6          7          6         11         19          23          28          20          20          23          25          28          43          43          50          35          30          44          42          33          45          56          50          43          46          32          40          30          30          38          33          26          24          25          30          22          15          19          16          12          10           8           9           6           6           6           8           4           3           1           1           1           0           0           0           2
```

with help was able to solve many of my problems but it keep reading the date wrong.

UPDATE 2:
I manage to fix the format from reading from the date adding a lambda to the apply.

```
data['#StartDate'] = data['#StartDate'].apply(str).apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%y%m%d'))
data['EndDate'] = data['EndDate'].apply(str).apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%y%m%d'))
```

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime()` and pass `format` argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `to_datetime` and `to_timedelta`:

```
data['new_StartDate'] = (pd.to_datetime(data['StartDate'], format='%Y%m%d') + 
                         pd.to_timedelta(data['StartTime']))

# similar for `EndDate` and `EndTime`
```

Comment: This was very helpful, but i still have the problem with the date, keep reading it wrong. I going to post the last format of what i've done in the post.